# Adding to the net command

Tags: windows, windows-services

Hey
Is there a way to adding tasks to the net command ?
for example i want to wrote to a log file each time i start and stop a service.

thanks

jerum

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "net command" ?

With a windows service, you can use OnStart and OnStop events to log.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct interface available for doing this. However, this can be done by manipulating a few things. If you are really interested in this, you can write a kernel driver that would trap (or hook) a few calls. If the function is called in context of `service control manager` then you can get the name of service that was being started/stopped and then you can add the appropriate logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a batch file wrapper for the `net` command and call that instead of `net`. I don't know if this is what you're after, but you can implement whatever functionality you like in the batch file:

**mynet.bat:**

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] goto end
net %*
echo %Date% %Time%: net %* >> "log.txt"
:end
```